# CRM Dynamics - Voice of the Customer (VoC) survey - Update Standard/Custom entities based on Survey Responses?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, survey

Is it possible to update standard and/or custom entities based on responses provided from a Dynamics CRM Voice of the Customer (VoC) survey?

According to Joel Lindstrom in [this blog](https://crmtipoftheday.com/992/updating-customer-data-from-survey-responses/), this is possible (at least for the Contact entity) via a workflow, but it doesn't actually show how to update a field on the contact entity.

Notes:
When I tried creating a workflow (as described in the link):

- I added an Update step, but the Contact entity wasn't available from the list of entities to update.
- I then added an Insert step and the contact entity **was** available.  (I don't count this as an acceptable option, because I want to update a record.  I don't want a second record.)

Answer (score 0):

If your workflow (W1) is on child Question response (QR), no direct Contact relationship is available. Only available on parent Survey Response (SR).

So you need a new Contact relationship in QR and another workflow (W2) to update this QR contact from SR. Then the W1 can be used to update the Contact fields like Phone # from one of the Survey Question response.

The [blog post](https://crmtipoftheday.com/992/updating-customer-data-from-survey-responses/) clearly says:

> The first challenge we are going to hit is that since the answer doesn’t have a direct relationship with contact, we can’t easily update the Contact record from a question response workflow. One way to resolve this is to add a relationship between question response and contact, and if the response is related to a contact, update the contact field on the question response to link it to the contact.